# Keyframing custom properties in panel not working

Tags: scripting, add-on, keyframes, geometry-nodes, drivers

I'm basically going nuts over this one.. well, I am actually

I'm trying to add keyframe/#frame from my addons panel.
I have created custom properties on the property group and everything is working as expected. But when I try to insert a keyframe in the panel on the property: I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\My_addon\properties.py",
line 873, in set_value
        amo = bpy.context.object.modifiers.active
    AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'object'
```

The keyframe doesn't update in panel, unless I'm hovering over the value. And it doesn't update at all in viewport.

Update function:

```
def Updatevaluesfunc(self, context):

    context.active_object.data.update()
    bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph.update()
    return
```

Getter/Setter

```
class SliderValues(PropertyGroup):

def uni_getter(attr_str):
    def get_value(self):
        activemodifier = bpy.context.object.modifiers.active
        return activemodifier[attr_str]
    return get_value

def uni_setter(attr_str):
    def set_value(self, value):
        amo = bpy.context.object.modifiers.active
        amo[attr_str] = value
    return set_value
```

Property in Propertygroup:

```
ResolutionProperty: IntProperty(
    name = "Resolution",
    description = "A IntProperty",
    default = 30,
    min = 3,
    max = 2147483647 - 1,
    update = Updatevaluesfunc,
    get = uni_getter("Input_14"),
    set = uni_setter("Input_14")
    )
```

I have searched everywhere and tried so much variations. What am I doing wrong

Comment: `bpy.context` doesn't have an `object` field. Did you mean `active_object`?

Comment: Thank you! That is correct and I managed to get the error away. Now the problem is actually different.. It does not print any errors, but it updates viewport only when hovering on right side of panel. I added also update_tag() to getter functions. I'm working with context so only the active object is getting the effects from keyframing, however the values work (per object) without keyframing -  (keeping the values)

Comment: And note: If I add for example #frame to the panel - it works only when hovering on panel. If I add it to geometry nodes input - it works as it should. If I add it to both with same value - it works. I think the question is, how to sync the keyframes to both